# Read .txt database (with datatool package) and format numbers with siunitx package

Tags: siunitx, datatool, database

I have a `variables.txt` file with the following content:

```
comp,232.429342
iva,1.9584000000000001
```

These are variables imported from a `main.py` file.
Using the `datatool` package, I have made a macro to read the database as follows:

```
\DTLsetseparator{,}
\DTLloaddb[noheader, keys={thekey,thevalue}]{python_variables}{variables.txt}
\newcommand{\pythonVar}[1]{\DTLfetch{python_variables}{thekey}{#1}{thevalue}}
```

So, when I want to show the content of variable `iva` I use the next command:

```
\pythonVar{iva}
```

And it works.

But when I use the `siunitx` package to correctly format numbers, an error occurs, e.g.:

```
\qty{\pythonVar{iva}}{\ampere}
```

The complete `LaTeX` code is:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{datatool}
\DTLsetseparator{,}
\DTLloaddb[noheader, keys={thekey,thevalue}]{python_variables}{variables.txt}
\newcommand{\pythonVar}[1]{\DTLfetch{python_variables}{thekey}{#1}{thevalue}}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
        Python variable: \pythonVar{iva}
        
        With unit: \qty{\pythonVar{iva}}{\ampere}
        
        Without unit: \num{\pythonVar{iva}}
\end{document}
```

This helps me to have a dynamical `LaTeX` document.

Answer (score 1):

The `\DTLfetch` command is intended to "fetch and display" a value. However, here you don't want to display the value but you want to use it for further processing through `siunitx`. For this you can use `\DTLgetvalueforkey` to store the value in a temporary variable and use this variable for further processing.

To do this you can define helper macros that first store the value and then immediately use it in either `\qty` or `\num`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{datatool}
\DTLsetseparator{,}
\DTLloaddb[noheader, keys={thekey,thevalue}]{python_variables}{variables.txt}
\newcommand{\pythonVar}[1]{\DTLfetch{python_variables}{thekey}{#1}{thevalue}}

\newcommand{\unitPythonVar}[2]{%
\DTLgetvalueforkey{\sitemp}{thevalue}{python_variables}{thekey}{#1}%
\qty{\sitemp}{#2}}

\newcommand{\noUnitPythonVar}[1]{%
\DTLgetvalueforkey{\sitemp}{thevalue}{python_variables}{thekey}{#1}%
\num{\sitemp}}

\begin{document}
        Python variable: \pythonVar{iva}
        
        With unit: \unitPythonVar{iva}{\ampere}
        
        Without unit: \noUnitPythonVar{iva}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]